# How can I quickly check which tensorflow variables are updated during training and which are frozen?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, pre-trained-model

I believe in a lot of scenarios, we need to freeze some layers in the tensorflow graph and keep other layers trainable.

Is there a method to quickly check if the network is trained as we expected? For example, the variables in the frozen layer are actually not updated during training.

I am using the following method to freeze all the variables in scope "ABC":

```
    with slim.arg_scope(inception.inceptionb_v2_arg_scope()):
        with tf.variable_scope('ABC'):
          _, end_points = getattr(inception, 'inception_v2'(..., is_training = False))
                         ......
    trainables = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if 'ABC/' not in v.name]
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, var_list= trainables)
```

What is the suggested way to quickly confirm these variables are really not changed during training?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just check them after a couple of iterations:

```
frozen_variables = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if 'ABC/' in v.name]
tmp_frozen_variables_np = sess.run(frozen_variables)
# Training Code
assert np.allclose(tmp_frozen_variables_np, sess.run(frozen_variables))
```

However, as long as they are not in the var list for the optimizer you should be fine.